# Send a Ajax Request , do I need open the firewall from customer ip to application server

Tags: web

I open a jsp page which load on a IHS Webserver，when I click a button on the jsp page ,the page send a ajax request to a Application server.
I am confused about  the request send from client or IHS?
I need open the firewall.

Comment: Is the AJAX request being made to a different server than your IHS Webserver?

Answer (score 0):

An AJAX request is typically performed by your browser.  Most of the time, you're just loading a page that performs some additional requests to the same server using JavaScript.  If the web page provided by your first server is making requests to a *different* server, you may encounter problems relating to CORS.  The admin of the Application server will need to configure headers that allow requests initiated by pages served from your first server.

Unless your firewall is very tightly configured to only allow whitelisted traffic, it's unlikely to require any changes.

Comment: Actually I don't want to ask the CORS problem, but thank you for reminding me about that .

Comment: My firewall only allow whitelist ip address, do I need open the wirewall between IHS and Application Server? or client an Application Server?

Comment: AJAX is typically implemented by using your browser to make requests to your Application server.  That said, I've seen instances of server-side AJAX requests.  It's less common, but possible.